# Reading values from plist nested dictionaries in shell script

Tags: macos, shell-script, dictionary, plist

I have a plist file and I'm interested in fetching values from nested dictionaries using shell script.
Here is the structure of my plist file:

```
<dict>
    <key>Countries</key>
    <dict>
        <key>USA</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Capital</key>
            <string>Washington DC</string>
            <key>Continent</key>
            <string>North America</string>
        </dict>
        <key>Italy</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Capital</key>
            <string>Rome</string>
            <key>Continent</key>
            <string>Europe</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I'm interested in fetching value assigned to the "Capital" key if user supplies a Country name.
For e.g If I execute the following command,I get the complete data under the "Countries" dictionary.

```
defaults read "/Users/sameerp/Downloads/data" Countries  2>&1
```

I get the following output:

```
{
    Italy = {
        Capital = Rome;
        Continent = Europe;
    };
    USA = {
        Capital = "Washington DC";
        Continent = "North America";
    };
}
```

How do I modify the command above to pass it the "Country" Key(USA for e.g.) and fetch the value for "Capital" Key?

Comment: So, what is your question? What do you have so far? You're not asking us to write the script for you right?

Comment: @terdon: I'm not asking anyone to write the script for me. I wanted to know if there is a direct way to access a key's value in nested dictionary using "defaults read" command.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

defaults can't do this without a lot of mess, but PlistBuddy will:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :Countries:USA:Capital" /Users/sameerp/Downloads/data.plist
```